# How to upload multiple files in several field of a form using php

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-file-upload

I have a form where 20+ fields are file type and each field have multiple attachment. So how can i upload multiple files each of the field and store the files url into mysql database.

I have did something like multiple attachment of a field. Created 2 tables where tableA has form data and tableB have files url with table1 parent_id.

But how can i handle 20+ field with multiple attachment. Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score -1):

I have set an example with 2 images (2 input fields) and 1 pdf file at the same time

So, I assume that you will have all the file inputs in your HTML markup, something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="PDF">
<input type="file" name="MainImage">
<input type="file" name="SecondImage[]">
```

In this case, to insert the file path of the uploaded file to the database, something like this should work:

```
$uploadMainTo = null;
if(isset($_FILES['MainImage'])){
  $main_image_name = $_FILES['MainImage']['name'];
  $main_image_size = $_FILES['MainImage']['size'];
  $main_image_tmp = $_FILES['MainImage']['tmp_name'];
  $uploadMainTo = $uploadLocation.$main_image_name;
  $moveMain = move_uploaded_file($main_image_tmp,$uploadMainTo);
}

$uploadSecondTo = array();
if(count(array_filter($_FILES['SecondImage']))>0){
  foreach(array_filter($_FILES['SecondImage']) as $value){
   $second_image_name = $value['name'];
   $second_image_size = $value['size'];
   $second_image_tmp = $value['tmp_name'];
   $uploadSecondTo[] = $uploadLocation.$second_image_name;
   $moveSecond = move_uploaded_file($second_image_tmp,$uploadSecondTo);
  }
  $uploadSecondTo = implode(',',$uploadSecondTo);
}

$uploadPdfTo = null;
if(isset($_FILES['PDF'])){
  $pdf_name = $_FILES['PDF']['name'];
  $pdf_size = $_FILES['PDF']['size'];
  $pdf_tmp = $_FILES['PDF']['tmp_name'];
  $uploadPdfTo = $uploadLocation.$pdf_name;
  $movepdf = move_uploaded_file($pdf_tmp,$uploadPdfTo);
}

$query = $db->execute("INSERT INTO users (pdf, main_image, second_image) VALUES (?,?,?) WHERE ID = ?", array($uploadPdfTo, $uploadMainTo, $uploadSecondTo, $user_id) );
```

I'm just not sure if i have to initialize the $uploadXTo variables with null or 'NULL'. If you have problems please test this way.

**NB** Don't forget to use enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: i have mentioned that each fields are multiple attachement. For example MainImage field have multiple attachemnt user can upload any thing pdf,docs, images, videos and others field(SecondImage) as well

Comment: I have just updated my answer on your Mentioned topic at SecondImage only as you see i have renamed the file of SecondImage[] and make it array and uploaded it by foreach loop